# How to implement a Expansion panel which is toggled/opened by default?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, npm, angular2-template

I have been styling the expansion panel which I installed using `npm`. I edited styling in `ng2-expansion-panels.bundle` present in `node_modules/ng2-expansion-panel/dist`, I wanted to have a opened/toggled expansion panel.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Yes please, if readers can see your code, they will have a better understanding of how your existing app works, and that will help them advise you on what you want now.

Comment: you can set [expanded]="true" on the expansion panel, <mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="true"> checkout the plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/XYleUMsFpOHZHSBBZAEu?p=preview